# Regular expression syntax In PHP to extract all instances of a format

Tags: php, regex, extract

I am attempting to extract all instances of a particular format from a string:

> I am wondering if my new Sony [PT# 123456ABC; Sony] has this feature but my friend says the new Toshiba [PT# AD-3232hjk; Toshiba] has this feature.

I would like to extract:

> [PT# 123456ABC; Sony]
>
> [PT# AD-3232hjk; Toshiba]

As you can see here, the only items in the consistent positions are:

- [PT#
- ;
- ]

I was attempting to use various types of strpos() but because of the varying lengths and formats of the part numbers and manufacturer names I was unable to reliably pull out those instances from a much larger string. I have been trying various ways to use regular expressions to solve this however my knowledge with them is fairly limited. After I have these expressions extracted and placed into variables I will then need to separate the part numbers and manufacturer names from the expression. This may also be easier to accomplish using regular expressions.

Any help is appreciated.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this would do it

```
preg_match_all( "/(\[PT#\s+.*?;\s+.*?\])/", $input, $matches );

print_r( $matches );
```

Altternatively, if you just wanted to capture the unique information

```
preg_match_all( "/\[PT#\s+(.*?);\s+(.*?)\]/", $input, $matches );
```

Comment: That works great thanks a lot! Now just to clarify that this is how preg_match_all operates - The output seams to duplicate data.

Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => [PT# 123456ABC; Sony]
            [1] => [PT# AD-3232hjk; Toshiba]
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => [PT# 123456ABC; Sony]
            [1] => [PT# AD-3232hjk; Toshiba]
        )

)

Comment: The 0 indexed array has all matches I believe and the 1 based has only what the parenthesis matched IIRC.

Answer (score 1):

```
$matches = array();
preg_match_all( "/\[PT#([^\];]+);([^\]]+)\]/", $input, $matches,  PREG_SET_ORDER);

foreach ($matches as $match) {
  echo "id=", trim($match[1]), " brand=", trim($match[2]), "\n";
}
```

Comment: \\[PT#\s([^;]++);\s([^\\]]++)\\] : Should be slightly faster, doesn't store backreferenes as they're not needed and it also takes white space into account, you can remove the need for trim then.

Answer (score 0):

I take it you'll be reading from a text file containing a lot of those entries. What you can do is:

```
preg_match_all("/\[PT#(.*?);[.*]?(.*?)\]/i", $text, $result);
```

it will put all matches into the array $result and you can access them as so:

```
echo $result[1][0]; //echos first occurrence's serial
```

$result is sorted column major and the first entry into a match is the complete match string

```
echo $result[0][0]; // would print [PT# 123456ABC; Sony]
echo $result[1][0]; // would print 123456ABC
echo $result[2][0]; // would print Sony
```

Hope that helps

EDIT: fixed the regex, should work now (still untested)

Comment: Unfortunately this outputs a blank array when attempting to print_r $result.

Comment: Thats what I get for deviating from my normal regex practices. code should work now.